# one form used in many html files

Tags: html, forms

I have thirty programs that use the same form.
I have the form coded in every single program.
It would be much better to have only one file to change if there is a need to change the form.
I tried inserting the form into my html code,
but it did not work.
This is a portion of the html form file -

```
document.write("<form  name="game">");
document.write("<pre>");
document.write("<textarea  name="status"  rows="8"  cols="16"  onfocus="stayAway()">");
document.write("</textarea><br>");
document.write("</pre>");
document.write("<p> <input  name="toGuess"  onfocus="stayAway()"  type="text"> <br>Word to guess.</p>");
document.write("<input  value=" A "  id="A"  onclick="guess('A')"  type="button">");
document.write("<input  value=" B "  id="B"  onclick="guess('B')"  type="button"html >");
document.write("</form>");
```

I named it hangman.html and I tried to insert it like this

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="../scripts/hangman.html"></script>
```

I have other html files in my scripts directory that are called like this, but the form simply does not display.  Is it a "form" issue that forms can't be inserted this way?
How do I insert a form into an html program so it can be used in many different programs?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You cannot use the `script` tag to include a `html` file.

Comment: What is the `file type` of your **"program"**?

Comment: If you want to learn how use `html` and the `tags` you can read [here](http://html.com/).

Comment: you have a lot of quote error, that is why it is not working. browser don't mind what extension you have as long as the file contains valid javascript.

Comment: Quotes! That caught me on other files too.  Had to use singles instead of doubles...  that has got to be it!  Thanks Bansi

Comment: make sure you escape properly `onclick="guess('A')"` <-- you need both type quote here

Comment: Yes Bansi... onclick=\"guess('A')\" worked like a charm. Now I can use this file in all my programs with a simple 
    <script  language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript"  src="../scripts/hangman.html"></script>
This is not a server side call and response form - like others tried to help with.  If you want to see it in action:  http://psych.techscholia.com/book/Mchapters/Preface.html and then click the hangman button

Answer (score 1):

In html page just you have to add class like this  and after that you will get the form in same html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".formContainer").append('<form name="game"> <div><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"> </div> <div><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"></div> <div><textarea name="status" rows="8" cols="16" placeholder="Message"></textarea></div> </form>')
  })
```

```css
  .formContainer input{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  .formContainer textarea{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="formContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use PHP, so what you could do is paste your code in an external file, say form.php like:

```
<?php
     echo "<form action.....>
        </form>";
?>
```

Then put this line wherever you want the form to show up:

```
<?php include 'form.php' ?>
```

This solution will require you to run Apache though.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this HTML code
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Form using JavaScript </title>

    <!-- include css file here-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css"/>  

</head>
<body>

   <div id="main">
   <h1>Contact Form using JavaScript</h1>
    <div id="form_sample">

    </div>
   <!-- include JavaScript file here -->
   <script src="js/form.js"></script>   


</body>
</html>

next use this javascript code

var x = document.getElementById("form_sample");

var createform = document.createElement('form'); // Create New Element form
    createform.setAttribute("action", "");        // Setting action Attribute on form
    createform.setAttribute("method", "post");  // Setting method Attribute on form
    x.appendChild(createform);

var heading = document.createElement('h2'); // Heading of form
    heading.innerHTML = "Contact Form ";  
    createform.appendChild(heading);

var line = document.createElement('hr');  //giving horizontal row after heading
    createform.appendChild(line);

var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
    createform.appendChild(linebreak);

var namelabel = document.createElement('label'); // Create Label for name field
    namelabel.innerHTML = "Your Name : ";            // Set Field Labels
    createform.appendChild(namelabel);

var inputelement = document.createElement('input'); // Create input field for name
    inputelement.setAttribute("type", "text");  
    inputelement.setAttribute("name", "fname");
    createform.appendChild(inputelement);

var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
    createform.appendChild(linebreak);


var emaillabel = document.createElement('label');  //Create Label for email field
    emaillabel.innerHTML = "Your Email : ";
    createform.appendChild(emaillabel);

var emailelement = document.createElement('input'); // Create input field for email
    emailelement.setAttribute("type", "text");
    emailelement.setAttribute("name", "demail");
    createform.appendChild(emailelement);

var emailbreak = document.createElement('br');
    createform.appendChild(emailbreak);

// Append Textarea
var messagelabel = document.createElement('label'); 
    messagelabel.innerHTML = "Your Message : ";
    createform.appendChild(messagelabel);

var texareaelement = document.createElement('textarea'); 
    texareaelement.setAttribute("name", "dmessage");
    createform.appendChild(texareaelement);

var messagebreak = document.createElement('br');
    createform.appendChild(messagebreak);

// Append Submit Button
var submitelement = document.createElement('input'); 
    submitelement.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    submitelement.setAttribute("name", "dsubmit");
    submitelement.setAttribute("onclick", "showInput();");
    submitelement.setAttribute("value", "Submit");
    createform.appendChild(submitelement);

use this css code

/* below line is write to use google font online  */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu);

div#main{
width: 830px;
height: 650px;
margin: 0px auto; 
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

div#form_sample{
text-align:center;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 300px;
padding: 0px 50px 15px;
margin-top:20px;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px;
border-radius: 6px;
float:left;
}

#main h1{
margin-top:40px; 
}

hr{
margin-top:-5px;
}

label{
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
}

input[type="text"]{
width:100%;
margin-top:10px;
height: 35px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
padding:10px;
border:3px solid #2BC1F2;
}

textarea{
width:100%;
border:3px solid #2BC1F2;
padding:10px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
margin-top: 10px;
height: 100px;
resize:none;
}

input[type="submit"]{
width:100%;
padding: 10px 45px;
background-color: #2BC1F2;
border: none;
color: white;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}


this time I am used this.
i hope you can easily understand this code.
```